# How do you move visual studio DataTip window

Tags: visual-studio

The window pops up below the variable, and obscures the code I want to look at.

Can I move the window without loosing my place in it? I seem to remember there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remembered [where I saw the tip](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2005/11/21/495496.aspx).

The answer is: you cannot move the window, but pressing Ctrl makes it transparent, which is as good.